# Spring-boot / Java Project Structure & Naming

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I would like to know the correct structure (in terms of which class to use) for a method to send a Message using a API.

My project listens for incoming JSON messages and then relays them using POST to another API.

So for the project has

```
Application Class (main method in here and @SpringBootApplication)
MessageController (controller to listen for incoming Messages)
MessageData (class with getters and setters for mapping incoming JSON)
```

Now I need a method to send (relay) the incoming message which is received by the controller.

Should this send method be in its own class (named?) or would it logically fit better somewhere else?

Comment: Usually you'd have some kind of service class in charge of sending the message (taking the message as a parameter of a "send" method). Remember the Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: Ideally YES, It depends. SINGLE RESPONSIBILITY is one of the most important OOPS principle. However you should also give importance to encapsulation. The decision has to be taken wisely depending upon what extend you want to go deeper. Is the class/structure is going to change very frequently? If changed, how difficult will it be to refactor the code, what are the efforts required to write perfectly OOPS code right away? everything has its own cost and benefits.